# Gather information via Terminal

Tags: terminal, bash

Looking for a couple of terminal commands that i can use to get the following -

- View domain name of current Windows AD a Mac is connected to
- Network link speed of en0
- Bios/EFI firmware date
- OSX Software GUID (or some such identifier)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: `man man` > `man -k <query>`

Answer (score 2):

Try `system_profiler` and `sysctl`.

Answer (score 1):

The commands you are looking for in the order listed

- To get the domain name, use `uname -n`.  The `-n` flag will give you the node name on your network.
- Use the command `ifconfig en0 | grep media` to print out information on the media of your selected interface.
- You can use `system_profiler SPHardwareDataType | grep -i "Version"` to get you the current firmware/ROM versions.
- If you are looking for info on the GPT partition map, use `sudo gpt show diskX` where X is the integer for the disk identifier

You can get more info on all of these commands by viewing their respective man pages (i.e. `man ifconfig`)

Comment: The last one is wrong. The GUIDs shown there are partition type UUIDs and aren't really related to OS X (software).

Comment: @4Maes-  What specifically are you looking for when you say "OS X Software GUID"?

Comment: Cheers for the replies. Looking for some type of unique identifier for the OS. i believe in Linux this is done with a GUID?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like-

```
 pkgutil --pkg-info com.apple.pkg.EmbeddedOSFirmware
```

for the firmware install date.

I'll leave the how to parse and convert the install time as an exercise for you.